# Collapse / Expand a specific cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have 2 categories (cat, dog) in 1 UITableView.

This is the illustration: [image]

The cat and dog button are part of the UITableView they are in the header section.
they act as a separator for both categories.

what i'm trying to achieve is when i click the cat button, the list under the cat button should collapse and the dog button should re - adjust it's position.
When i click again the cat button, the list should expand.

what i currently have is :

```
NSUInteger indexes = (unsigned long)filteredList.count;
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= indexes - 1 ; i++)
    {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [self.accountBalanceTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].hidden = YES;
    }
```

It hides all of my cat list but the dog button is not adjusting it's position where it just leaves a huge amount of white space in the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expandable tableView in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626028/expandable-tableview-in-iphone)

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: try this ==> https://stackoverflow.com/a/46952115/8303852

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya updated my question

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities you can do this.

- Change the height of the rows in the section you want to hide.
- Return 0 for the rows in the section you want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

[image: You want like this??]

you can use two cell(maincell,subcell)in your table and put this code in cell for row at indexpath.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    if (tableView == _tblDispChapters) {

        if(indexPath.row == 0){

            TVCDispChapters *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

            //Accuracy
            int acu;
            if ([[marrParentChapters objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]valueForKey:@"acuracy"]==[NSNull null] ) {
                 NSLog(@"%@",[[marrParentChapters objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]valueForKey:@"acuracy"]);
                acu=0;
            }
            else
            {
                acu=[[[marrParentChapters objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]valueForKey:@"acuracy"] intValue];
                NSLog(@"%d",acu);
            }

            cell.lbl_acu.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Accuracy %d%%",acu];
            [cell.pro_cell_chapt.layer setCornerRadius:cell.pro_cell_chapt.frame.size.height/2];
            cell.pro_cell_chapt.clipsToBounds = true;
            [cell.pro_cell_chapt setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 2.0f)];

            cell.pro_cell_chapt.progress =  acu/100.0;
            cell.pro_cell_chapt.trackTintColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:0xDDDDDD];
            cell.pro_cell_chapt.progressTintColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:0xEF9430];


            cell.lblChepterName.text = [[marrParentChapters objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]valueForKey:@"ChapterName"];
            [cell.btn_sel_allchptr setTag:indexPath.section];
            [cell.btn_sel_allchptr addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            if ([[_marrHideShowSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue]){
                [cell.imgArrow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up-arrow1"]];
            }else{
                [cell.imgArrow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down-arrow1"]];

            }

            if ([[_marrAllChapter objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue]){
                [cell.img_cpt_select setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-selected1"]];
            }else{
                [cell.img_cpt_select setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-unselected1"]];
            }
            return cell;
        }else{
            TVCDispChapters *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sub_Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.lblSubChapterName.text = [[[marrSubChapters objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1]valueForKey:@"ChapterName"];

            if ([[[_marrSelectionSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1] boolValue])
            {
                [cell.imgSelection setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-selected1"]];
            }else{
                [cell.imgSelection setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-unselected1"]];
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }else{

        QuestionTypeTVC *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellQuesType" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if ([_marrSelectedQuestionypeID containsObject:[[_marrQuestiontype objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"QuestionTypeID"]]){
            cell1.imgSelection.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-selected1"];
        }else{
            cell1.imgSelection.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-unselected1"];
        }
        cell1.lblQuesType.text=@"1";
        return cell1;
    }
}
```